# Testing a Key with cartesian coordinates in my dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
    def __eq__(self, other):

        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self))


class Piece:


    def __init__(self, color, type_piece):
        self.color = color
        self.type_piece = type_piece

    def is_pawn(self):

        return self.type_piece == "pawn"

    def is_queen(self):
        return self.type_piece == "queen"

    def is_white(self):
        return self.color == "white"

    def is_balck(self):
        return self.color == "black"

    def change(self):
        self.type_piece = "queen"

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.is_white() and self.is_pawn():
            return "o"
        elif self.is_white() and self.is_queen():
            return "O"
        elif self.is_black() and self.is_pawn():
            return "x"
        else:
            return "X"

class board:

    def __init__(self):
        self.n_x = 8
        self.n_y = 8

        self.cases = { Position(1,1):Piece("white","pawn") }  #example of what my dict contains

    def check_piece(self, position):

        if Position(position) in self.cases.keys():
            return cases.get(Position(position))
        else:
            return False
```

when i try check_piece((1,1))

TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'colonne'

and when i try check_piece(1,1)

TypeError: recuperer_piece_a_position() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given...

any help would be appreciated, I can not change the structure of the Dictionary as it is prebuilt

Comment: Seems like there not enough information about your classes and objects. Also, there is more neat construction like `cases.get(something, False)`

Comment: Unfortunatelly I may not post all the classes & let alone the whole homework, currently im stuck with these two error messages and am unable to retireve the value of my key in order to continue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_piece` takes one argument, whereas `Position` takes two.

Try something like

```
def check_piece(position):

    return cases.get(Position(*position), False)
```

and `check_piece((1,1))` will work.

Comment: why is there a star (*) before position?

Comment: It unpacks the tuple, so that each element is used as one argument for the function. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Very much appreciated